# strict doctype and inline css

Tags: css, doctype

In my html file, when I write this, it is displayed correct.

```
<div class="event" style="top: 30px; left: 10px; width: 584px; height: 80px;">
```

But as soon as I set strict doctype, the styling goes away. So in firbug I see only style="".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>.....<body>
<div class="event" style=""></div></body></html>
```

Complete html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>calendar</title>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

    body {
    font-family:arial;
    margin:10px;
    }
    #canvas {
    width:600px;
    height:720px;
    padding:0 10px;
    background:#ececec;
    margin-left:75px;
    position:relative;
    }

    .event {
    padding:5px;
    border:solid #d5d5d5;
    border-left:solid #aaa;
    border-width:1px 1px 1px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    max-width:600px;
    background:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    div.event .title {
    font-size:1em;
    colo:#4B6EA9;
    }
    div.event .desc {
    font-size:0.8em;
    color:#7a7a7a;
    }
    #time {
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    }
    div#time .timeline {
    height:60px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#7a7a7a;
    }
    div#time div.timeline span {
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-left:7px;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#aaa;
    }
    div#time div.timeline .last{margin-top:35px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="time">
<div class="timeline">9:00<span>AM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">10:00<span>AM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">11:00<span>AM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">12:00<span>PM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">1:00<span>PM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">2:00<span>PM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">3:00<span>PM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">4:00<span>PM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">5:00<span>PM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">6:00<span>PM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">7:00<span>PM</span></div>
<div class="timeline">8:00<span>PM</span><div class="last">9:00<span>PM</span></div></div>
</div>
<div id="canvas">
<div class="event" style="top: 30; left: 10; width: 584; height: 80;">test</div><div class="event" style="top: 610; left: 10; width: 284; height: 50;">test</div></div> </body></html>
```

Comment: Can we see the CSS for the `event` class?

Comment: updated complete html code with css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't specifying any units in your inline styles. This will work in quirks mode (no doctype) but not in strict mode (with doctype).

```
<div class="event" style="top: 30px; left: 10px; width: 584px; height: 80px;">
```

should fix it.

Comment: yeah.. i just figured that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured out the problem.

Instead of

```
style="top: 30; left: 10; width: 584; height: 80;"
```

it should be

```
style="top: 30px; left: 10px; width: 584px; height: 80px;"
```

Earlier it worked because it was not using strict doctype.